# How to set mongodb aggregate default value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to assign a default value of zero on days with zero repair, but this is the result.

```
   [
      { day: 21, month: 10, year: 2022, count: 2 },
      { day: 28, month: 10, year: 2022, count: 1 },
      { day: 24, month: 10, year: 2022, count: 2 }
    ]
```

I just need to access the weekly repair data, 0 should be the default on non-repair days

```
const result = await Repair.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdDate: {
                        $gte: new Date(fromDate),
                        $lte: new Date(toDate),
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        day: "$day",
                        year: "$year",
                        month: "$month",
                    },
                    count: {
                        $sum: 1,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    day: "$_id.day",
                    month: "$_id.month",
                    year: "$_id.year",
                    count: "$count",
                },
            },
        ]);
```

Comment: can you give sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: data: [30, 40, 100, 80, 75, 105, 90] @Takis

Comment: i dont understand what data means, if you can give 1-2 documents in json, and the expected output after the query.

Comment: The values in the data[ ] represent the daily repair total. output should be like this. @takis

Comment: Which version do you run? Latest MongoDB version 6.0 provides [$densify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/) which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, i use Latest version @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without valid sample input data, it is difficult to give exact solution, but would be like this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         createdDate: {
            $gte: new Date(fromDate),
            $lte: new Date(toDate),
         },
      },
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$createdDate", unit: "day" } },
         count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
   },
   { $set: { createdDate: "$_id" } },
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "createdDate",
         range: {
            step: 1,
            unit: "day",
            bounds: "full"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $fill: {
         sortBy: { createdDate: 1 },
         output: { count: { value: 0 } }
      }
   }
]);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FLk6lnjLAbU)

**Update**

With MongoDB version 5 the code is a bit more complex. Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdDate: {
        $gt: new Date("2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      repairs: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$createdDate", unit: "day" } },
            count: { $count: {} }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            date: "$_id",
            count: "$count",
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      allDays: {
        $range: [
          0,
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $dateDiff: {
                  startDate: { $min: "$repairs.date" },
                  endDate: { $max: "$repairs.date" },
                  /*
                  or
                  startDate: new Date("2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
                  endDate: new Date("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                  */
                  unit: "day",
                }
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      allDays: {
        $map: {
          input: "$allDays",
          in: {
            $dateAdd: {
              startDate: { $min: "$repairs.date" },
              unit: "day",
              amount: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      repairs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$allDays",
          as: "day",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              { date: "$$day", count: 0 },
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$repairs",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$day",
                        "$$repairs.date"
                      ]
                    },
                    as: "repairs"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      repairs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$repairs",
          in: "$$this.count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g5j_8ehr2Xb)

The result cannot be simple `[ 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 ]`, the result is always a JSON document, i.e. field and values. But you can do

```
db.collection.aggregate([...]).toArray().shift().repairs
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not return any results, it may be due to the version.

Comment: As said, without valid input sample data it is difficult to provide a solution. As you see in the playground, the aggregation pipeline is working.

Comment: I use 5.0.13 verison

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$densify' @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: You said "latest version" which is 6.0. In 5.0 you need a bit more code but without sample input data it doesn't make much sense to develop a solution.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8829001b9825cd356247153fff96214e20221029092928/c82381  Can you take a look at the json data, it should default to 0 on days of inactivity.

Comment: Example result >> data: [30, 40, 0, 80, 75, 0, 90]

Comment: I did not ask for the entire data set. Please edit your question and add some **sample** which have only the data which are relevant for your question. And the expected result should match the sample input data.

Comment: what should i use instead of just densify