# How to get record count in last X days in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database where I keep repair information, I need to list them using Chartjs. Simply, the number of repairs made in the last 7 days should be listed daily, and the days of no action are 0 by default.

Repairs Collection >> https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8829001b9825cd356247153fff96214e20221029092928/c82381
Example result >> data: [30, 40, 0, 80, 75, 0, 90]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as long as you save the repair date on the document, this can be easily done using an aggregation pipeline.

#### Solution

We will start by first matching all the relevant repairs, done in the dates we would like to filter out. This can be done using a `$match` stage:

```js
{
  $match: {
    createdDate: {
      $gt: `Your start date`,
      $lt: `Your end date`
    }
  }
}
```

After we have the relevant repairs, we can then continue and group them by date and counting repairs by date. This can be done using a `$group` stage:

```js
{
  $group: {
    _id: {$dateToString: {date: '$createdDate', format: '%Y-%m-%d'}},
    repairs: {$sum: 1}
  }
}
```

Now we have x documents (depending on the date range you need), looking like this:

```js
{
  "_id": `date`,
  "repairs": `amount of repairs`
}
```

#### Example

Using the stages mentioned above, I created a pipeline that is outputting the amount of repairs for each day between 23.10.22 to 29.10.22.

```js
[{
 $match: {
  createdDate: {
   $gt: new Date('2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z'),
   $lt: new Date('2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z')
  }
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: {
   $dateToString: {
    date: '$createdDate',
    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
   }
  },
  repairs: {
   $sum: 1
  }
 }
}]
```

The following will return this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-23",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-24",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-25",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-26",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-27",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-28",
    "repairs": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-10-29",
    "repairs": 10
  }
]
```

#### Sources

- [Aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/)
- [$match stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-match)
- [$group stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group)

### Edit

This can also be done using the `$dateTrunc` operator that was added on mongodb version 5.0.

The pipeline will look like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdDate: {
        $gt: new Date("2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$createdDate",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      repairs: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: not the total number of repairs between two dates, 24.10=5repairs, 25.10=10repairs.......

Comment: example result >>>> data: [30, 40, 0, 80, 75, 0, 90]

Comment: Yup, this is what it does.

Comment: It will look more like:
[{_id: '24.10', repairs: 10}, {_id: '25.10', repairs: 20}] and so on

Comment: I trying but result undefined

Comment: plesae use mongoplayground after send link ?

Comment: You need to change `date` to `createdDate`. Here is the playground link:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y8K8W1JFOpZ

Comment: but non-repair days should default to zero

Comment: This will need to be done via JavaScript, mongodb can only work with the data it has.

Comment: Of course, you can do it purely with an aggregation pipeline. In MongoDB version 6.0 you can use [$densify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/). In older versions, you have to do it manually with `$range`, `$map` and `$filter`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74236186/3027266